# Python Django: getting started with mocks

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following code that I'm attempting to create a test (still work in progress):

```
from core.tests import BaseTestCase                                                                          
from core.views import get_request                                                                           

from entidades.forms import InstituicaoForm                                                                  
from mock import patch                                                                                       


class InstituicaoFormTestCase(BaseTestCase):                                                                 

    def setUp(self):                                                                                         
        super(InstituicaoFormTestCase, self).setUp()                                                         

    @patch('get_request', return_value={'user': 'usuario_qualquer'})                                         
    def test_salva_instituicao_quando_informaram_convenio():                                                    
        import pdb                                                                                              
        pdb.set_trace()                                                                                         
        form = InstituicaoForm()
```

it fails because when I try to create a InstituicaoForm, a get_request is called:

```
def get_request():
    return getattr(THREAD_LOCAL, 'request', None)
```

and it trows this error

```
entidades/tests.py:11: in <module>
    class InstituicaoFormTestCase(BaseTestCase):
entidades/tests.py:16: in InstituicaoFormTestCase
    @patch('get_request', return_value={'user': 'usuario_qualquer'})
.tox/unit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py:1670: in patch
    getter, attribute = _get_target(target)
.tox/unit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py:1522: in _get_target
    (target,))
E   TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'get_request'
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> entering PDB >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
> /home/vinicius/telessaude/.tox/unit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py(1522)_get_target()
-> (target,))
```

What am I doing wrong? How should mock this get_request() method?

Comment: See the mock docs on [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch). Note that using threadlocals is generally considered a bad idea, and there is rarely a need to do so in Django code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the specific thing you're trying to do can be done like this:

```
@patch('core.views.get_request', return_value={'user': 'usuario_qualquer'})
```

But you should also look at the [Django testing documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/), if you haven't already. You can use the testing client to fake the web request.

If you want to experiment with mock tests that don't access a database, check out [Django Mock Queries](https://github.com/stphivos/django-mock-queries). (I'm a small contributor to that project.) I've also tried mocking views, but it's fiddly.